# Reading txt file data into doubles

Tags: java, arrays, double, bufferedreader, filereader

I am trying to save data in a text file to an array containing doubles. I have made it work for integers, but I want to add non integer data and so far I can't figure out. Here is my code so far:

public class MainClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<Double> E0 = Arrays.asList();
    List<Double> E1 = Arrays.asList();
    List<Double> E2 = Arrays.asList();
    List<Double> C = Arrays.asList();
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Data.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            Double lineParts = line.split(",");
            E0.add(lineParts[0]);
            E1.add(lineParts[1]); 
            E2.add(lineParts[2]);
            C.add(lineParts[3]);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(E0);
        System.out.println(E1);
        System.out.println(E2);
        System.out.println(C);
    }

}
```

Here is my data:

1,1,4,-1
1,2,9,1
1,5,6,1
1,4,5,1
1,6,7,-1
1,1,1,-1

Comment: read them as Strings, and parse them to doubles

Comment: Please don't add things like _"[SOLVED]"_ to question titles. The appropriate way of doing that is accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete answer to your question is to convert the static separating method with full dynamic parsing method without any error, This answer is safest possible solution that doesn't depend on how long is your inserted data.

you can achieve this with the help of a **list** containing **list of double values**

Sample with your data:

```
List<List<Double>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Data.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            List<Double> lineList = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] lineParts = line.split(",");
            for (String linePart : lineParts) {
                lineList.add(Double.valueOf(linePart));
            }
            lines.add(lineList);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(lines);
}
```

Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows how to parse a line and convert the entries to double.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ParseDouble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "1,2,3,-4";
        String[] lineSplit = line.split(",");
        double[] values = new double[lineSplit.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < lineSplit.length; i++) {
            values[i] = Double.parseDouble(lineSplit[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values)); // [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, -4.0]
    }

}
```

Using your code, the following lines should do the job:

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<Double> E0 = new ArrayList();
    List<Double> E1 = new ArrayList();
    List<Double> E2 = new ArrayList();
    List<Double> C = new ArrayList();
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Data.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            String[] lineParts = line.split(",");
            E0.add(Double.parseDouble(lineParts[0]));
            E1.add(Double.parseDouble(lineParts[1])); 
            E2.add(Double.parseDouble(lineParts[2]));
            C.add(Double.parseDouble(lineParts[3]));
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(E0.toArray()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(E1.toArray()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(E2.toArray()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(C.toArray()));
    }

}
```

Comment: When I run it, it repeatedly prints the first line in an array double then gives error:   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:153)
 at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:111)
 at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:21)

Comment: I corrected my answer. I changed `List<Double> E0 = Arrays.asList();` to `List<Double> E0 = new ArrayList();`. Accordingly, I have done this for the other lists as well.